# PHP Form + Jquery Changing <select> name attribute = No Data?

Tags: php, jquery, web-applications

let me just get to the problem:

I have an upload script in PHP that takes data from my form, then uploads the file to the appropriate folder based on the form data. My form has 2 "fields" (besides the file itself): the "**subject**" field and the "**subset**" field.

I say 2 "fields" because my HTML consists of 1 subject select and 6 subset selects. I use JQuery to show/hide the subset selects (see below).

[Video of this in action (pardon the large watermark)](https://streamable.com/q2jvf)

HTML:

```
<!--subject-->

<select name="subject">
  <option value="1">
  <option value="2">
</select>


<!--subsets-->

<select name="subset" id="1">
  <option value="a">
  <option value="b">
</select>

<select name="subset" id="2">
  <option value="c">
  <option value="d">
</select>
```

Along with this HTML, I have JQuery that changes the: a) visibility, b) name, and c) required property of the select fields.

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#subject').change(function() {
        //reset visibility, required, and name
        $('.subset').hide();
        $('.subset').attr('name', "off");
        $('.subset').prop('required', false);

        //set correct subset's values
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).attr('name', "subset");
        $('#' + $(this).val()).prop('required', true);
    });
});
```

This allows me to only take the value with the select with the name "**subset**", and ignore the ones with the name "**off**". However, when submitting the form, my script redirects me to error.php, a sign I'm not doing something right.

PHP for setting variables "subject" and "subset":

```
if (isset($_POST['subject']) && $_POST['subject'] !== '') {
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);

    if (isset($_POST['subset']) && $_POST['subset'] !== '') {
        $subset = trim($_POST['subset']);
    } else {
        die(header('Location: error.php'));
    }
    //if (isset($_POST['teacher']))
    //    $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['teacher']);
} else {
    die(header('Location: error.php'));
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is caused and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Just because you hide something with jQuery, doesn't mean it's not send with the form. Most likely your `$_POST['subset']` is being overwritten with an empty value (because you use the same name attribute value for each of em) by the last subset in your form that was hidden. As an extra tip: Use `!empty($_POST['...'])` instead of `(isset($_POST['...']) && $_POST['...'] !== '')`. It does exactly the same.

Comment: @icecub The JQuery changes the name of the other subset selects to the value "off", how would that overwrite the select with the name "subset"? (https://streamable.com/r8ll0 shows that all other selects have the name "off"). Also, thanks for the PHP tip, I'll use that!

Comment: If that's the case, you need to start debugging with more usefull messages so you know exactly what's going on. Instead of redirecting to error.php, `if(!isset($_POST['subject'])){ die("Error: subject doesn't exist!"); } else { die("Error: subject is empty!"); }`. Do the same for subset. It's a lot harder to pinpoint the problem if you don't know exactly where it goes wrong.

Comment: Also, if your jQuery / html is exactly like that, it'll never trigger. You have: `<select name="subject">` and `$('#subject').change`. The event listener is set to the id attribute with the value subject. You don't have an id attribute in your select field here? Though I'm assuming this is just a typo you made here.